# Getting L2TP up and running on a 2012 R2 Server

Tags: vpn

I found what I thought was a good guide to setting up L2TP VPN Access on a 2012 R2 Server. It lead me to believe I needed to let ports 500, 1701 and 4500 UDP through the firewall and port forward them to the server. That is the first question. Was that article correct?

If that is correct then shouldn't I be able to do a netstat -ano on this server and see it listening on ports 500, 1701 and 4500? Because right now that netstat command doesn't show any UDP ports period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, you just need *udp/500*, *udp/450*0 **and** *ipsec es*p (and  *ipsec a*h, but the latter is quite improbable) to be forwarded from the firewall to the LNS. You don't need *udp/1701* since it will be encapsulated in either *ipsec esp* ot in *NAT-T udp/4500* if it will be negotiated, so you won't see it on the wire.
2. Since you cannot forward any ipsec frames properly from the firewall, this blocks the ability to the client to use anything except NAT-T. Furthermore, forwarding service port from firewall is generally a bad idea. You should assign public IP to the LNS, with or without ***dot1q vlans***. Anyway, any NATed installations nowadays tend to be quite cumbersome and difficult to debug.
3. It is also a generally bad idea to use Windows and a VPN gateway, since it really isn't a network OS, rather a rudimentary landmark from the past, but this is up to you. I'd rather use Linux/FreeBSD/Cicso/Juniper and so on. Any network OS virtual appliance would fit, you can even run it on your Windows hyper-V.
4. UDP ports aren't listened on (since `listen()` call is for TCP sockets), they're just opened with another call called `bind()`, that's why you don't see any `LISTEN` lines in the `netstat -an` output.

Comment: For the background I usually use Sonicwall GVC but this one particular company got stuck using a Pepwave router and just needs one person to have VPN. No VLANS. This is just a simple Windows domain. 1 server and 10 workstations. So it sounds like you are saying there is no way to even know if the right ports are open and forwarded properly anywhere in the chain?